# Flutter gRPC error - OS Error: Connection refused

Tags: dart, flutter, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using protobuf and gRPC to exchange information between a Flutter app and a python server (client in Flutter and the server in python). Server running on 0.0.0.0 and the client is using the IP address of the server machine.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'User.pbgrpc.dart';
import 'User.pb.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';

Future<Null> main() async {
  final channel = new ClientChannel('IP_ADDRESS',
      port: 50051,
      options: const ChannelOptions(
          credentials: const ChannelCredentials.insecure()));
  final stub = new StorageClient(channel);

  Test input = new Test();
  input.id = 1;
  try {
    var response = await stub.getPerson(input);
    print('Greeter client received: ${response}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Caught error: $e');
  }
  await channel.shutdown();
}
```

if I run this client using `dart client.dart` everything works fine and I get the expected response. But if I embed this method in a flutter app like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Future<Null> testRPC() async {
  final channel = new ClientChannel('IP_ADDRESS',
      port: 50051,
      options: const ChannelOptions(
          credentials: const ChannelCredentials.insecure()));
  final stub = new StorageClient(channel);

  Test input = new Test();
  input.id = 1;
  try {
    var response = await stub.getPerson(input);
    print('Greeter client received: ${response}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Caught error: $e');
  }
  await channel.shutdown();
}

testRPC();
...etc
}
```

I get:

```
I/flutter (18824): Caught error: gRPC Error (14, Error connecting: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 45638)
```

**UPDATE:** It is working when I run the app with an emulator. So this is error is happening only when using a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was a firewall problem. Running `systemctl stop firewalld` on the server solved it.

Comment: Maybe not. I do not have `firewalld` running and still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you run AVD(Client) and the backend in same computer， you have to set the base URL instead of "localhost/127.0.0.1" to "10.0.2.2".

Here's the answer in [Github](https://github.com/hillelcoren/flutter-redux-starter/issues/16).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, Flutter app as grpc client and C# as grpc server. The problem was in the server, I was using "localhost" as host parameter, changed to "0.0.0.0" and now is running fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add network permission to android project:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.client">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <application
        android:label="client"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```